# combination of a sequence in desired format

Tags: python

How do I get a sequence of a string - `"1317"` in following array format ?
Possible arrays are

```
[1317],[131,7],[13,17],[1,317],[13,1,7],[1,31,7],[1,3,17],[1,3,1,7]
```

I have tried it using `itertools` function but it is not resulting in the desired format.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a recursive function to generate all possible combinations of the sequence.

```py
def split_string(s, index=0, current_split=None):
    if current_split is None:
        current_split = []
    if index == len(s):
        result.append(current_split)
        return
    # Case 1: Create a new number with the current digit
    split_string(s, index + 1, current_split + [int(s[index])])
    # Case 2: Append the current digit to the last number in the current split
    if current_split:
        new_split = current_split[:-1] + [current_split[-1] * 10 + int(s[index])]
        split_string(s, index + 1, new_split)

result = []
s = "1317"
split_string(s)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think of your possible string as `1_3_1_7` where the place holder can be a `,` or empty char depending on a True/False flag. To get all combinations, you can use itertools to generate every combination of 3 True/False choices with `it.product([True, False], repeat = 3)`.

The code below effectively does this using list comprehension:

```
num = "1317"

splits = [
    "".join(
        [digit + ("," if comma else "") for digit, comma in zip(num, commas)]
        + [num[-1]]
    )
    for commas in it.product([True, False], repeat=3)
]

print(splits)
```

Output:

```
['1,3,1,7', '1,3,17', '1,31,7', '1,317', '13,1,7', '13,17', '131,7', '1317']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a generator with [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

def combination_split(s):
    n = len(s)
    for r in range(len(s)):
        for c in combinations(range(1, len(s)), r=r):
            yield [s[start:end] for start, end
                   in zip((0,)+c, c+(len(s),))]
                
out = list(combination_split('1317'))
```

If you prefer a classical function:

```
from itertools import combinations

def combination_split(s):
    n = len(s)
    out = []
    for r in range(len(s)):
        for c in combinations(range(1, len(s)), r=r):
            out.append([s[start:end] for start, end
                        in zip((0,)+c, c+(len(s),))])
    return out
                
out = combination_split('1317')
```

Output:

```
[['1317'],
 ['1', '317'],
 ['13', '17'],
 ['131', '7'],
 ['1', '3', '17'],
 ['1', '31', '7'],
 ['13', '1', '7'],
 ['1', '3', '1', '7']]
```